# Android - GCM push notification that sends user to Activity does not result in onCreate call

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am able to create push notifications, and to send the user to whichever Activity I want, but I notice that whenever the user lands on that Activity, the onCreate function does not get called.

Is that supposed to be the case? How do I set it so that the onCreate of the Activity is called?

Here is my Activity:

```
public class QuestionActivity extends BaseListActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

and here is how the notification is generated:

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    if ( notification_type != null && notification_type.equals("question"))
    {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, QuestionActivity.class);
    }
    else
    if ( notification_type != null && notification_type.equals("plan"))
    {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, TopicActivity.class);              
    }

    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);        
    Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);            

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
     .setContentTitle(title)
     .setContentText(message)
     .setContentIntent(intent)
     .setSmallIcon(icon)
     .setLights(Color.YELLOW, 1, 2)
     .setAutoCancel(true)
     .setSound(defaultSound)
     .build();

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you `@Override` those methods? Post your code.

Comment: @323go override which method?  And which code should I post?

Comment: Post the code you are using to start the activity.

Comment: I just posted the activity start and the code to create the push notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flags that you are using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` mean that if the activity is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, the old existing activity will be used. In that case `onCreate` won't be called, since the activity already exists.

Comment: @Genadinik That depends on what you are trying to achieve. If your app is already running, and the relevant activity already exists, do you really need to create a new instance of that activity, or can you use the existing one?

Comment: well, I need it to reload that screen so it can pull things from the server.

Comment: @Genadinik Well, perhaps you can reload data from your server in `onResume` instead of `onCreate`. The decision whether to use these flags or not depends on how you want the activity that you open from the notification to be related to the rest of your app (for example, which activity will be opened when you tap the back button from that activity).