# Android Notification Handling Suggestions

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, push-notification, android-pendingintent

So I have a basic notification application.  Here's the current configuration details:

```
GCMIntentService

NotificationActivity
:
---->ViewMessageActivity
     :
     ---->ViewUserDetailsActivity
```

`GCMIntentService` is configured to do the following: Upon receiving a notification, a pending intent with `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` is created and the intent adds the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag.

Currently, I have my `NotificationActivity` defined in my manifest as `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`.  If I set it to `android:launchMode="singleTop"`, when the user clicks the notification a few things can happen depending on Android Version (or so my two devices show)

1. In Android < 2.3, If I'm in another activity (say `ViewMessageActivity`) and I press the notification from the shade, nothing happens (I don't receive anything from `onNewIntent`)
2. In Android 4.2 (Not sure about other versions), If I'm in another activity (say `ViewMessageActivity`) and I press the notification from the shade, nothing happens (I don't receive anything from `onNewIntent`) *AND* the notification disappears from the shade
3. If I'm in `NotificationActivity` everything works great regardless of version

So this led me to set it to `singleInstance` instead of `singleTop`.  Now when the user presses the notification and the user is in a different activity (say `ViewMessageActivity`), the notifications intent is handled appropriately HOWEVER, my `NotificationActivity` tries to create a new instance of `ViewMessageActivity` for the message clicked in the notification shade and it does not create a new activity.  Instead, shows my already opened instance.  I've tried adding flags such as `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` but neither my `onCreate` or `onNewIntent` methods are called in my `ViewMessageActivity`.

Ideally, this is what I would like to happen:  When the user has navigated to another activity (say `ViewMessageActivity`) from the main activity (`NotificationActivity`) and the user presses a notification from the notification shade, I would like the NotificationActivity to be flagged to update its ListView view `onNewIntent` which will create another ViewMessageActivity instance.  Note: I have no launchMode option set for any other activity.

Any suggestions?

Vince

Comment: It would help if you include the code that opens the activity when you tap the notification. And you should look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375926/android-cgm-push-notification-that-sends-user-to-activity-does-not-result-in-o) question, which is quite similar

Comment: I was actually able to resolve it by using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` which provides the functionality I was wanting.  Cheers.